# Trix WYSIWYG tab index not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, trix

I have multiple trix inputs on a form.  Usually in forms when you press the tab key within a form input: it jumps you to the next form input.  I noticed that on a desktop computer: tabbing for trix inputs actually tabs you through all the trix toolbar buttons before finally getting to the next input.  Interestingly: it works as expected with an iPad and bluetooth keyboard.

This issue was pointed out on trix's github: [located here](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/322).  The issue was closed though since there were work arounds posted on there that apparently fix the issue.  Here is one of the suggestions:

```
for (var element of event.target.toolbarElement.querySelectorAll("button")) {
  element.tabIndex = -1
}
```

However, when I plugged that into my app and I looked at the front-end error logs, here is what it says:

> TypeError: element of event.target.toolbarElement.querySelectorAll is not a function. (In 'element of event.target.toolbarElement.querySelectorAll("button")', 'element of event.target.toolbarElement.querySelectorAll' is undefined)

I trust that the solution works, but I am probably missing something. I not extremely familiar with javascript, so the error message is a bit cryptic to me.

- [trix documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/trix)
- I don't think this applies here: but I am using this in a rails project, and I bring trix in via the [trix gem](https://github.com/maclover7/trix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to change the syntax, and it worked:

```
document.addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
  var elementButtons = event.target.toolbarElement.querySelectorAll("button")

  for (i=0; i<elementButtons.length; i++) {
    elementButtons[i].tabIndex = -1 ;
  }
})
```